# MonoGame VertexPositionColor draws in incorrect place

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm trying to make a rendering library for monogame and I'm currently working on drawing 2D polygons. However, The positions don't make any sense. Somehow, drawing them at (0, 0, 0), (100. 0, 0), (0, 100, 0), and (100, 100, 0) doesn't reach the top-left coordinate (0, 0). How do I fix this?

My Code:

```
 BasicEffect basicEffect = new BasicEffect(GraphicsDevice);  
 VertexPositionColor[] vert = new VertexPositionColor[4];  
 vert[0].Position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);  
 vert[1].Position = new Vector3(100, 0, 0);  
 vert[2].Position = new Vector3(0, 100, 0);  
 vert[3].Position = new Vector3(100, 100, 0); 
 short[] ind = new short[6];  
 ind[0] = 0;  
 ind[1] = 2;  
 ind[2] = 1;  
 ind[3] = 1;  
 ind[4] = 2;  
 ind[5] = 3;  
 foreach (EffectPass effectPass in basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)   
 {  
     effectPass.Apply();  
     GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(  
     PrimitiveType.TriangleList, vert, 0, vert.Length, ind, 0, ind.Length / 3);

}
```

RESULT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUhUG.jpg

Answer (score 1):

MonoGame uses a different origin for 2D and 3D coordinate systems. In 2D, (0, 0) is top-left corner, and Y increases toward the bottom of the screen. In 3D, (0,0,0) is the *center of the screen*, and the coordinate grid works very much like it does in mathematics - think 4 quadrants in math, if you "flatten" the z-axis.

You're drawing in Quadrant I. If you want the drawing to be based on top-left corner, you need to *translate* your vertices by -1/2 your viewport width and +1/2 your viewport height.

Comment: Thanks! Are the unit lengths still the same? (EX: Is adding 1 to the x coordinate in 3D equivalent to adding 1 to the x coordinate in 2D?)

Comment: Not exactly. Typically, you'd use a *camera* with 3D, which can significantly change how your shapes are represented. I can draw a 2x2 *pixels* square in 2D, and have it take up the entire screen... So, adding 1 will change by 1 *unit*, but the resulting drawing might not at all change by 1 *pixel*

Comment: Okay, thaks. Do you know of any way to draw these vertices at 2D coordinates or convert the coordinates to/from 2D coordinates?

I really appreciate the help, btw.

Comment: Look into https://github.com/craftworkgames/MonoGame.Extended - lots of cool extras, including 2D Camera, and `SpriteBatch` extensions (like `SpriteBatch.DrawCircle()`, etc). It's open source, MIT license, so you can use it, adapt to your needs, etc.

Comment: thanks, I'll check it out. Have a great day/night/evening/morning/afternoon!